# cx_Oracle: Adding foreign key constraints to a table implies it will populate that said table or not?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle11g, cx-oracle

The table 'likes' is using the primary key(s) of tables users and pictures as its (foreign key) attributes. When I am trying to execute the below code I am getting no value for like(Please see I have added values to both users and pictures table and those table values are getting displayed):

```
statement = """CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id number(10) not null PRIMARY KEY,
    username Varchar2(50),
    user_email Varchar2(50),
    no_of_liked_pictures number(10),
    last_login Date
    )"""

cur.execute(statement)
statement = """create table pictures(
                picture_id number(10) not null  primary key,
                pic_path varchar2(200),
                pic_caption varchar2(500),
                no_of_likes number(10),
                date_of_post date
                )"""

cur.execute(statement)
statement = """create table likes(
                picture_id number(10),
                user_id number(10),
                constraint fk_pic foreign key (picture_id) references pictures(picture_id),
                constraint fk_user foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
                )
            """
cur.execute(statement)
cur.execute("select * from likes")
print("likes Table:\n",cur.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating foreign key constraints on a table just means that you can only put in the data from values that are present in a column you're referencing to. It doesn't mean that it populates the data - it merely keeps the integrity of the data you put in `likes` table, so that you can't have a `user_id` or `picture_id` which isn't present in respectively `users` or `pictures` table.

Table `likes` is a different table and unless you add some data to it, there's nothing to `SELECT` from it.

You need to `INSERT` your data first to `likes` table in order to be able to see it. It isn't a view of other tables.

What you created is a many-to-many relationship, so that you can now connect users with their pictures in table `likes`. Also, consider creating a `PRIMARY KEY` on columns `(picture_id, user_id)` in your `likes` table.

Comment: I realised that must be the case. Although thanks for the help and insight.

Comment: Note, that there's no way it could actually populate the table. Despite the fact that it is a totally different table storing different information, the database would have no way of deciding which user is connected with which picture.